# In platformer video games, what is the term for the size of the character on the screen?

Tags: platformer, terminology, screen

In 2D platformer games, what is the term or word for determining the size of the player character on the screen?

For example, the player character in *Castlevania: Symphony of the Night* is very small on the screen.

Comment: Are you looking for FOV (field of view)?

Comment: @starikcetin No. I am talking about the size of the player character in platformer 2D video games.

Comment: The size of the player character on the screen is called "the character size relative to the screen" 

Comment: @Theraot why are you rude in your answer?

Comment: @JamesAnderson I don't think rudeness was intended, simply that they mean that there is no specific term for that and that you coined the most appropriate way to name the concept.

Comment: I'd upvote that as an answer — I don't think there's any more official term to offer.

Comment: If something about "the character size relative to the screen" isn't capturing what you're asking about, please edit to include how that's falling short. There are other things that may impact or be impacted by character / sprite size (such as field of view) & it may just be that we need more information to get on the same page as you. If you recall having heard / read the term somewhere, include whatever you can recall about the encounter.

Comment: If you don't care about relative size maybe absolute size or pixel size if it is pixel graphics?

Answer (score 3):

While I agree that there's no consensus to define *a character's size relative to the screen* with a specific word, you can always relate two homogeneous quantities by defining a **ratio** between them. Now you can use your brand-new *player-to-screen* width/height ratio and incorporate it in your design.

Most engines use **world units** to give meaning to spatial measurements internally, but this doesn't prevent you to define [your own unit of measurement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_unusual_units_of_measurement) for designing levels, objects, obstacles, etc. In fact, computing a ratio can also answer "*How many of X fit in Y?*" so you're expressing the screen width/height in terms of your character size.

As a designer, you want your numbers to assume values that achieve your game design goals. Your units of measurement are your own, and you can call them whatever you want:

- "My character is 1x2 **CharSquares** when standing up."
- "This chasm is 4 **Crates** wide, and my character is 1 **Crate**. If they run at 2 **Crates/second** top, they should be able to jump over it without falling."
- "Player's avatar is 2 **Tiles** wide, and I want their maximum view distance to be 15 **Tiles** on either side. Therefore, I need to fit my camera to a total width of 32 **Tiles** horizontally, and doing so will result in a vertical viewing distance being..."